# How to divide a graph into connected components?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have some edges:

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 8 -> 10};
```

And I make a graph:

```
g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: graph with 3 connected groups]

After seeing the graph, you realize that there are three separate sub-graphs or families in it, and I want to see them separately. This is what I have done:

```
families = {Subgraph[g, {1, 2, 3, 6}], Subgraph[g, {4, 5}], Subgraph[g, {7, 8, 9, 10}]};
nMax = 3;
Manipulate[families[[n]], {n, 1, nMax, 1}]
```

[image: manipulate generated graph viewer]

I would like to know how to calculate `nMax` and `families` automatically. My real problem has thousands of edges and it is not viable to do it visually.

Comment: Have a look at [Kosaraju's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju's_algorithm) I had to implement this for Coursera's algorithms class and it worked great even on huge graphs (5 million edges)

Comment: @IvoFlipse Thank you for the link. Computing Leonid's answer for my 3.3 million edges took less than 4 seconds on my laptop.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Subgraph[g, #, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10] & /@ 
    ConnectedComponents[UndirectedGraph[g]]
```

[image]

The proper terminology for what you asked, as hinted by the code, is *connected components* of a graph. I had to convert a graph to undirected one, since connectivity in a directed graph is a stronger condition, and not what you were after here.